# Is there a Python package similar to Perl's Archive::Extract?

Tags: python, zip, gzip, extract, archive

I'm looking for a package that will automatically detect the type of and extract an archive (zip, tar.gz, etc).  In Perl, this is easy - in Python, I can't find any simple package/class to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riding off of [Mark Byers' response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549134/is-there-a-python-package-similar-to-perls-archiveextract/2549150#2549150), perhaps you can tie all of these together with `mimetypes` (also from the standard library).  You could identify the type of file, and process it accordingly. The world needs a Python version of `Archive::Extract`, and we want you to write it!

Comment: Don't use `mimetypes`. Use `magic` instead, although it's not part of the stdlib.

Comment: I looked at using magic, but was hoping there was something already out there...
May have to write it!

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use:

- [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html)
- [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) - Note: Tarfile can also handle bz2ed and gzipped tar files.
- [bz2](http://docs.python.org/library/bz2.html)
- [gzip](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html)

I'm not aware of any wrapper that can choose the right format automatically. If it exists it doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation for any of the above modules.